# Has anyone used AmpScript to add data to a custom field added to the ET IER record?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

We would like to keep all email details together.  We have some content that sends links to documents we would like to note were sent in Salesforce for users that aren't ET users.

It would be ideal to populate a custom field on the ExactTarget Individual Email Result object.
I've tried parsing out the Merge ID field to the first 15 characters to pull in the record ID and use that to reference in an UpdateSalesforceObject("et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c"...) script.

It looks like this:

```
%%[ 
var @result set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c",SUBSTRING(et4ae5__MergeId__c,1,15),"Digital_Catalog_Received__c","2014-15") 
]%%
```

So notice a digital asset was sent for the year 2014-15.  Any thoughts on why this may not be working?

I've tried first 18 characters, first 15 characters and the entire Merge ID.  I would like to avoid creating a custom field on my contact record to populate, but will if necessary.  It would be better to keep all email details on the same object record...

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: is this object locked? as it's part of a managed package.